# Как задать разную ширину для изображения в галерее в зависимости от размеров (ориентации) изображения

Tags: html, css, flexbox, img, layout

Сверстал такую галерею, но проблема в следующем. Все картинки одинаковых пропорций. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы те изображения, которые в альбомной ориентации сохраняли свои пропорции. То есть ширина так и была больше высоты. Но высота изображений в рамках одного ряда была по-прежнему одинаковой.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbnQO.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijkmz.jpg

Comment: Задайте фиксированную высоту, а ширину не трогайте, ну или на крайний случай сделайте ```max-width```.

Answer (score 0):

Масштабирование изображений с сохранением пропорций можно реализовать множеством способов. Здесь приведу только два из них, которые сам использую чаще всего.

#### Ограничение размеров `img` по элементу-обертке

Классический кроссбраузерный способ: помещаем `img` в `div` (например), и указываем в стилях `width`|`max-width` и/или `height`|`max-height` со значением `100%`:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.row { display: flex; gap: 0.5rem; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 0.5rem; background: #eee; }
.row .img-wrap { height: 110px; }

.img-wrap > img { height: 100%; }  /* ◄◄◄ */
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img-wrap">  <!-- ◄◄◄ -->
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=0">
  </div>                  <!-- ◄◄◄ -->
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/180/110/cats/?r=1">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=2">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=3">
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/90/55/cats/?r=4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Нюанс: лучше избегать одновременного указания `width: 100%;` и `height: 100%;` - потому что при несовпадении соотношений сторон изображения и обертки, это приведет к искажению. С `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;` такого не случится, но изображение конечно не будет масштабироваться "вверх" до родительских размеров (обертки) при превышении собственных.

#### `object-fit`

Всего лишь `object-fit: contain;` в стилях - это суперпросто, суперудобно, правда без поддержки в IE (которую до сих пор просят иногда):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.row { display: flex; gap: 0.5rem; flex-wrap: wrap; padding: 0.5rem; background: #eee; }

.row > img { height: 110px; object-fit: contain; }  /* ◄◄◄ */
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=0">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/180/110/cats/?r=1">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=2">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/110/180/cats/?r=3">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/90/55/cats/?r=4">
</div>
```

---

<sub>Примеры респонсивны - сохранение высоты изображений при их переносе (от flex-wrap), можно проверить уменьшив окно браузера.
  
Одно последнее изображение в каждом примере масштабируется "вверх", а остальные изображения уменьшаются при необходимости (второй сценарий гораздо более частый).</sub>